# VSCode and omnisharp select Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I'm learning C# using Visual Studio Code in Linux.
The thing is that when I have 2 or more projects I select the one in omnisharp, but keeps dubugging, compiling the first one.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have same issue, with multiple .NET Console Apps.